# How to Make Zend_Controller_Router resets un-wanted parameter by default

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, urlhelper

I'm using Zend-Framework 1.9.5 to make a web-application, But it's Url_Helper was quite tricky to me in the matter of parameter reset!, I know it's a good feature (parameter preserving) but in most cases I don't need it!.
So I'm thinking of overriding the default Router to force it loosing parameters Unless I ask for it or maybe specifying a certain parameters that it keeps like (lang, or something like that).

Also I want to make it the default router so I don't have to edit my Controllers, Views to get that done!

Any suggestions?

**Update:**
I spent the whole morning trying to write my url helper `Admin_View_Helper_Xurl`, But I couldn't do anything that solves the problem:

```
<?php
class Admin_View_Helper_Xurl extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
     public function xurl(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = 'default', $reset = false, $encode = true)
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

        $wanted_params = array('module', 'controller', 'action', 'lang', 'page', 'search');

        $route = $router->getCurrentRoute();

        $something = anyWayToGetThatObjectOrClass();

        $params = $something->getParams();

        foreach($params as $key => $val) {
            if (!in_array($key, $wanted_params)) {
                $params[$key] = null; // OR uset($params[$key]);
            }
        }

        $something->clearParams();
        $something->setParams($params);

        return $router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode);
    }
}
```

I tried to get current URL parameters and filter them and clear the current parameters and pass my filtered ones but I couldn't do anything that does it without hard-code editing one Zend_Framework code :(.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you override the helper instead - it passes on the call, except reset parameter is `true` by default.

Comment: I tried this and it turns out that it also resets the controller, action, module! not just the parameters!. I looks like I have to go deeper and override a lot of things!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution. It took 7 hours to be functional.

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Xurl extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{

    const RESET_ALL = 'all';
    const RESET_CUSTOM = 'normal';
    const RESET_NON_MVC = 'mvc';
    const RESET_NONE = 'none';


    protected $_wantedParams = array('module', 'controller', 'action', 'lang', 'page', 'search');
    protected $_router;  
    /**
     * Generates an url given the name of a route.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param  array $urlOptions Options passed to the assemble method of the Route object.
     * @param  mixed $name The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route
     * @param  bool $reset Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided
     * @return string Url for the link href attribute.
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $this->_router = clone $router;
    }

    public function xurl(array $urlOptions = array(), $reset = 'mvc', $encode = true)
    {
        $urlOptions = $this->_getFilteredParams($urlOptions, $reset);
        return $this->_router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, true, $encode);
    }

    protected function _getFilteredParams($data = array(), $level)
    {
        // $filteredValues = array();
        $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
        $filteredValues = $request->getUserParams();
        $$filteredValues['module']     = $request->getModuleName();
        $$filteredValues['controller'] = $request->getControllerName();
        $$filteredValues['action']     = $request->getActionName();


        switch ($level) {
            case self::RESET_ALL:
                $filteredValues['module'] = null;
                $filteredValues['controller'] = null;
                $filteredValues['action'] = null;
            // break omitted intentionally
            case self::RESET_NON_MVC:
                $filteredValues['page'] = null;
                $filteredValues['lang'] = null;
                $filteredValues['search'] = null;
            // break omitted intentionally

            case self::RESET_CUSTOM:
                foreach ($filteredValues as $key=>$val) {
                    if (!in_array($key, $this->_wantedParams)) {
                        $filteredValues[$key] = null;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case self::RESET_NONE:
                break;

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException('Unsuppoted Xurl URL helper reset level.');
                break;
        }


        foreach ($filteredValues as $key => $val) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $data)) {
                $data[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Clearly it's a View Helper class, may be not the best solution but it works fine with me  for now.

Answer (score 2):

When generating a link a view, you can ask the helper to get rid of all aparamters with a simple boolean :

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', action => 'action'), 'default', true); ?>
```

The last parameter tells whether to reset parameters or not.

Comment: I tried this and it turns out that it also resets the controller, action, module! not just the parameters!. I looks like I have to go deeper and override a lot of things!.